# Deleting a Realm object bound to ListView on Android Studio

Tags: android, realm

I have been working with Android Studio and Realm to create an app for chess noting. The thing is that whenever I delete a 'Game' (Class I created) the last one in the list takes the place of the deleted one (i.e. ListView with "Games" 'a' through 'h', I delete Game 'c', then Game 'h' takes the place of the 'c') and I'd like to know if anyone has had the same problem and how did you solve it. Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is that you are relying on the position inside the result set, instead of storing it along with the data.

Comment: So you're saying I should store the position along with the model?

Comment: Well actually I guess you are just supposed to ensure a sort order with `findAllSorted`

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured that out hours after I posted this xD Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in Realm is unsorted by default and we do not give any guarantees about the position if you do not provide a sorting. What you are seeing is actually the expected behavior in the case where you delete data as we will take the last item and put it into the now empty spot (to avoid null values in our internal data structure).

Using `findAllSorted()` instead of `findAll()` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! Very Helpful!